# ionic/angular 2 receive a list of declared modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ng-modules

Tell me please, how to receive a list all classes, which was declared in @NgModule.

Which modules I have in @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyApp, AuthPage, HomePage]
})
```

And example of I want to receive:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    this.ngModule.declarations.getClasses() // should return something like: [[MyApp, AuthPage, HomePage]]
  }
}
```

How can I receive a list of declarations or providers?

Comment: No it is not possible, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Oh. I need a method, which will return me a class instance by their string name. For example, I want to call a method with "MyApp" param and receive MyApp as a class. As a workaround, I can implement classes as AppModule properties, but I don't want to make class declarations twice, in NgModule and in AppModule.